# Как парсить Json строку в С?

Tags: c, json, curl

Ради шутки решил попробовать получить Json и парсить в структуру на С. Для получения Json строки использую `libcurl`. Данные приходят но стал вопрос как парсить приходящую информацию? Ведь насколько я понял `libcurl` используется только для транспортировки файлов и не более.

Получаю информацию так:

```
int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    struct string receiveString;
    initString(&receiveString);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, TARGET_URL);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writeFunction);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &receiveString);


    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    printf("%s\n", receiveString.stringPointer);
    free(receiveString.stringPointer);

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

где `receiveStrong.stringPointer` полученый результат.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очевидно, если не хотите писать парсер своими руками, то надо найти библиотеку, которая умеет это делать. На [json.org](http://www.json.org/) есть список таких библиотек для разных языков программирования. Выбирайте то, что покажется проще:

- JSON_checker
- YAJL
- LibU
- json-c
- json-parser
- jsonsl
- WJElement
- M's JSON parser
- cJSON
- Jansson
- jsmn
- parson
- ujson4c
- nxjson
- frozen
- microjson